# Testing Subscription.create - is there a fake paymentToken to use?

Tags: braintree

I need to test my subscription.create code. Can I do that with a fake paymentMethodToken or do I have to create the customer/payment to get the token?

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work as a developer at Braintree</sub>

The best way to test your subscription is through your Sandbox account.

1. [Create or login](https://www.braintreepayments.com/get-started) to your Sandbox account.
2. Set up the [plan](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/guides/recurring-billing/plans#creating-a-plan) you would like to test.
3. Create a test customer and a payment method using one of these [testing values](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/testing).
4. Create a subscription with the token from the payment method you created with the test values.

Comment: This is not working for the Ruby SDK. Transactions work but Subscriptions do not.